# Spring-WS and Straight-JPA (EclipseLink) Configuration and Deployment

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, spring-ws

I've implemented an EJB3 / JPA web service without any major problems, and now I've moved on a Spring-WS/JPA web service. Both are being deployed to Glassfish.

My understanding of JPA is limited, but by default transactions are container managed? How do you change this? With EJB3 things were straight forward as I could just inject the `EntityManager` in to the "DAO" (a discussion for another time!) with `@PersistentContext` and the container would take care of transaction demarcation. In terms of basic configuration that's about it. As the container uses JTA then I've specified the transaction type "JTA" on the persistence unit. In my very simple example application with one persistence unit I do not have to care about its name - Do things get more complicated if you have multiple persistence units or will the container take care of this?

Now I've built an equivelent web service with Spring-WS and have reused my entities/dao's, but I've struggled to get it working. I've included in my application context a bean definition for the `EntityManagerFactory` (`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`) as well as for the `JpaTransationManager` (bean reference to `EntityManagerFactory`). I've also included the `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and the `tx` namespace. I wouldn't have thought I'd need to do anything else but it wont deploy with a *No persistence providers available for "null"* error.

Do I need to specify the actual persistence unit I want to create a manager for?

Thanks,

Update:

Ok, I'm getting the following error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named null.

It's probably my spring configuration for the factory/manager:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManager" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

I think I may need or inject something else in to it...

Another update:

Fixed that issue - Was using the `LocalEntityManager` instead of `LocalContainerEntityManager`.

Now I'm having problems persisting my objects. I have a parent object with a child object as a property. I can see the child object being persisted in the logs when I call `em.persist(parent)`, but the parent doesn't get persisted.

Last update:

The parent object was getting persisted, but the transaction had not committed before I tried to retrieve it (I'm mocking without mocking so to speak). Think I've got the jist of it now.

Comment: This seems to be an entirely different problem now. I suggest posting another question (with code to illustrate the problem etc).

Comment: Managed to fix it (see edit). Didn't think it was pertinent to post a new question now.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of JPA is limited, but by default transactions are container managed?

In a Java EE environment, the default entity manager type for a session bean is *container-managed* and *transaction-scoped*.

> How do you change this?

Change what exactly? And in what context? In an Java EE environment, you would have to use a Bean Managed Transaction (BMT) session bean and to control a `UserTransaction`.

> Do things get more complicated if you have multiple persistence units or will the container take care of this?

I'm not sure about this one, it might be container specific. So if you have multiple persistence units, my advice would be to define the `unitName`.

> Now I've built an equivelent web service with Spring-WS (...) Do I need to specify the actual persistence unit I want to create a manager for?

This shouldn't be required. This [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2008/jw-05-spring-seam3.html?page=4) provides a nice summary of the default mechanisms (maybe it's explained in the documentation too but I couldn't find something as succinct):

> Spring's
>   `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`
>   loads the persistence unit
>   configuration from the persistence
>   unit descriptor (e.g.,
>   `META-INF/persistence.xml`) whose name
>   is equivalent to the value of the
>   `persistenceUnitName` property specified
>   on this factory bean (refer to
>   Listings 1 and 2). If a persistence
>   unit name is not provided, the first
>   configuration in the persistence unit
>   descriptor is selected. The injection
>   of the persistence manager into
>   properties of Spring beans annotated
>   with `@PersistenceContext` is handled by
>   a special bean post-processor, which
>   must be registered in the Spring
>   configuration file, shown in Listing 9.
>
> (...)
>
> When Spring encounters a
>   `@PersistenceContext` annotation on a
>   bean property, it uses the value of
>   the annotation's `unitName` attribute to
>   locate an
>   `EntityManagerFactory`-producing factory
>   bean with a matching
>   `persistenceUnitName` property value,
>   matching against the bean ID as a
>   fallback. If a `unitName` attribute is
>   not specified in the annotation, then
>   Spring uses the first
>   `EntityManagerFactory`-producing factory
>   bean defined in the Spring
>   configuration. An example of using the
>   `@PersistenceContext` to inject a
>   transaction-scoped `EntityManager` into
>   a Spring bean is shown in Listing 10.
>   (If there is only a single persistence
>   unit in your application, you can
>   safely leave off the `unitName`
>   attribute.) (...)

Back to your problem, my suggestions would be to:

- update your question with the relevant bits of your `persistence.xml` and Spring configuration
- activate logging (in particular of `org.springframework.orm`) to see if everything goes well at initialization time
- see what you get when you specify the `unitName`

Comment: Cheers fella, I'll get the relevant snippets up later.